# Is there such a thing as Unit Test Plan

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I worked on a **Java/Java EE** project and i have to deliver a **Unit Test Plan**, i've worked on many integration tests plans, which describes integration tests scenarios, but i've never heard of Unit Test Plan.

This Unit Test Plan have to describe the **Unit Tests** i've done, and their related rule in the specifications.

Is there such thing in java project life cycle ? if yes, where can i have an **example**, or **how to make one**.

Comment: Read this: http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/how-to-write-test-plan-document-software-testing-training-day3/

Comment: There's nothing specifically that has to do with Java and unit test plans - your question is not specific to Java or any other programming language.

Comment: A "Unit Test Plan" is an artefact that was often a deliverable for projects running a waterfall process in the 90s.

Comment: If someone is asking you to produce such a thing,  they must have a definition of what it is. What does their definition say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests should be self explanatory.

They are used by programmers to be sure that their code is correct and doesn't affect existing code.

Any programmer should be free to add new tests if necessary, so maintain a document to define the plan of unit tests is a very strange approach.

From my point of view, a test plan should be used to define acceptance tests or integration tests, not for unit tests.

Note that unit tests are useful during the programming phase and during the programming phase is not possible to know exactly which tests will be written. So it is possible to imagine that a unit test plan will be written only at the end of the work when a plan is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

To a certain degree, your question sounds more like an invitation to a discussion, but anyway:

At least in their [stricter](http://artofunittesting.com/) sense, unit tests are very much "developers business". You as a developer create "white box" tests that run at compile time to create feedback from *running* code.

Of course, some project manager could now come up with the idea that he/she needs you to exactly "plan" your unit test activities.

In my eyes, that would be a violation of anything agile stands for. You see: in **agile**, one thinks about *features* that give value to the customer. You, the developer, you are going to create classes that implement features, but all of these "implementation details" only matter to you. Your project manager should not care how your design looks like, and how many classes it contains. So he really shouldn't ask you to make a plan **upfront** on your unit tests. Heck: you create classes (and tests for them) on an **agile** basis; but you are supposed to know **upfront** what you will be developing?!

Long story short: the PM should worry about planing those "customer features"; so it is fair when your PM asks about integration or system test plans on that scope; but you better challenge his idea of **him** overseeing **your** unit tests!

Comment: I don't disagree with your statements. However unit tests hook into the concept of code test coverage analysis that do bubble outside of the domain of "developer business" as its part of the overall quality of the deliverable.

Comment: @Gimby Sure; but again: if your PM starts telling you the coverage you **must** achieve, something is wrong. TDD and unit testing help you achieving high coverage; but somebody else giving you a goal ... is again, not "agile" in my eyes.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer i was trying to make them happy with Sonar and JavaDoc reports which are generated automatically, advancing the argument that there is no such thing in java project life cycle, so i want to be sure about my argumentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently asked, by a new manager, what test plan and test report we had for the latest version of our software. My reply:

- We develop our programs using Test Driven Development.  That constitutes our Test Plan.
- We never release a version that fails any automated tests, so releasing it means it has passed 100% of our automated tests. That constitutes our Test Report.

The manager seemed satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Test plan is extremely helpful. In larger organizations, when you are turning over a release to QA, you want to break your discussions along various planes. QA team is not going to look at your code and not supposed to. I'll give you an example. Did we test all compliance requests, persistence, feature X, feature Y. How good is coverage for critical feature Z and so on? There might have been an interesting email or point made by user about feature X, let's turn that into a unit test. There was a bug in previous version. You start tracking tests. QA and other devs can read descriptions.

It sounds silly and redundant but when you get to thousands of tests or as I have seen 30K tests in one git repo, you begin to scratch your head. I have rarely seen people retire tests. It is up to you how much detail to put into each description and design. Some developers go light on testing just so that Sonar report looks ok. Others would religiously write a test and description for every function, aiming for 100% code coverage.

Depending on your architecture, you have to understand the difference between testing a micro service and testing an application. I personally prefer to come up with an decent test plan for my app which includes unit tests and some integration tests. It is a living document.

How and when does it help you? When you have various versions of the application in production, you can compare test coverage between version X and Y. It also makes you scrum very straightforward. When you say dev complete, you show how much test coverage there is and discuss comfort level.

In many organizations, build time is a problem. Usually, it's due to long running tests. If you had a test plan and wanted to ship just your application, you could have an "app set" test suite and reduce your build time.

There is a number of vendor tools with nice HTML UIs. They do a decent job organizing your thoughts.

Comment: So you really list all your unit tests in an extra document? And every time you create a new class, you update that document? And everybody else does that, too? Long story short: I think you aren't talking about unit tests, in the narrow sense of the word. You are talking functional/integration testing.

Comment: @GhostCat, we did not log each test in a separate document although there was a high level jive document describing testing requirements. indeed that would be tedious. used vendor tool and java annotations to include specific unit and integration tests in a versioned release plan. it does take time to set this model up.